# Passing 2 parameters to a single class through map[x][y]

Tags: c#

**Goal:**

I’m currently working on an addition to an already existing library (a maze generator). What I’m trying to do is define a new way of storing the maze (partially in memory and partially on the hard disk).

*-Skip to the Problem paragraph if you just want to see the question. I added some extra information since you might suggest a completely other approach.*

**Current situation:**

The current way the maze generator stores mazes (in memory) is with a Map. The Map contains a bunch of InnerMapArrays which each contain a line of pixels in the maze. Points can be read/written in the maze like this:

```
… //Code that creates maze map
map[x][y] = true;
```

In the Map class there’s a method to return the correct array (x)

```
public override InnerMapArray this[int x]
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    get
    {
        return innerData[x];
    }
}
```

Then it will call [y] on the innerData which also contains a similar method to ultimately return the right pixel.

**Problem:**

Going back to what I want to do is create a new Map type that saves parts of the maze in memory and parts of the maze on the disk. I want to load areas of the maze in sets of 100x100 pixels for example, not by line. (In the image below the red part should be loaded when pixel x=50,y=50 is changed for example)

[image: Red square is the part that should currently be loaded in the memory]

The current implementation of the Map/InnerMapArray structure does not allow for this. What I want is a way to actually get the X and Y that are passed in one method.
What I thought that could possibly work is the following **(not working code)**:

```
public override InnerMapArray this[int x][int y]
{
    get
    {
        //load a certain 100x100 part of the maze in memory and set it as current
        //so while generating the maze pixels near the currently generated/read pixel
        //can be read really fast while others far away won't use any memory
    }
}
```

Sadly the C# compiler doesn’t allow this. Does anyone have a clue that could help me solve this issue in a ‘nice’ way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to achieve what you want is:

```
public overrride InnerMapArray this[int x, int y] { ... }
```

This code works only if you have a "double" indexer like this to be overriden in de base class of course. Hope this helps :)

Comment: This could be the solution, it would still mean that I have to edit the base classes of the already existing code. Something I was originally planning not to do. If this is the only way though, I guess that's what I have to do :)

Comment: I chose to use your solution and actually got an increase in performance compared to my current solution. Thanks for the help :).